# Move icon from jbutton to jbutton

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, move

I setup a gridlayout, with 16 buttons in the center. I placed an icon on the first button.

How would I loop through, and when the user select the next button on the grid, it moves the icon from old position to new position?

```
private ArrayList<JButton> grid = new ArrayList<JButton>(); 

JPanel gridBtnPanel = new JPanel();
gridBtnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
for(int i = 0; i <= 16; i++){
    JButton innerButton = new JButton();
    gridBtnPanel.add(innerButton);
    grid.add(innerButton);
}

ImageIcon player= new ImageIcon("player.JPG");

//starting position     
grid.get(0).setIcon(player);

//wanting to move to next button when I select the near by button       
for(int i = 0; i < grid.lastIndexOf(theifPerson); i++){
    grid.get(i).setIcon(null);
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: How about removing the icon from the previous button (i -1), and then just setting it to the new one (current i).

Answer (score 1):

You could add actionlisteners to the buttons, and once a button is pressed it searches through all the buttons to find one with a non-null icon, and switches the pressed button's icon with the non-null icon

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have some kind of `ActionListener` attached to each `JButton` so you know when the user clicks on one, if you don't, take a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

When the user clicks on a button, the `actionPerformed` method is called.  Here you want to determine which button was clicked, set the icon property of the last button to `null` and set the icon of the clicked button...

This will require you to know the last "active" button

```
private int activeButton;
private ImageIcon player;
//...
grid.get(0).setIcon(player);
activeButton = 0;
```

Then you simply want to update the current state...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object source = evt.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton clicked = (JButton)source;
        grid.get(activeButton).setIcon(null);
        clicked.setIcon(player);
        activeButton = grid.indexOf(clicked);
    }
}
```

For example...